# Dividing each row by the previous row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe of stock pricings.

| Date | CSCO | INTC | MSFT | WBA |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2003-01-03 | 10 | 9 | 8 | 6 |
| 2003-01-04 | 9 | 9 | 6 | 4 |
| 2003-01-05 | 8 | 9 | 5 | 3 |

How do I create a new Dataframe that takes today's price for one stock, and divide it by yesterdays price to return a ratio. Example output

| Date | CSCO | INTC | MSFT | WBA |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2003-01-03 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 2003-01-04 | 0.9 | 1.0 | 0.75 | 0.666 |
| 2003-01-05 | 0.88889 | 1.0 | 0.83333 | 0.75 |

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following. Simple explanation would be, creating 2 variables m1 and m2. Where m1 has everything from CSCO column to rest of the columns with shift shifting rows with 1. In m2 having everything from CSCO column to till last column value, finally dividing them to get values.

```
m1 = df.loc[:,'CSCO':].shift()
m2 = df.loc[:,'CSCO':]
df.loc[:,'CSCO':] = m2/m1
```

Output of DataFrame will be as follows:

```
         Date      CSCO  INTC      MSFT       WBA
0  2003-01-03       NaN   NaN       NaN       NaN
1  2003-01-04  0.900000   1.0  0.750000  0.666667
2  2003-01-05  0.888889   1.0  0.833333  0.750000
```

Answer (score 1):

In the solution we are dividing current row by previous row using [shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html)

**Code**

```
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date) # If required
df = df.set_index('Date')
df = (df/df.shift(1)).reset_index()
df
```

**Output**

```
    Date        CSCO        INTC    MSFT        WBA
0   2003-01-03  NaN         NaN     NaN         NaN
1   2003-01-04  0.900000    1.0     0.750000    0.666667
2   2003-01-05  0.888889    1.0     0.833333    0.750000
```